# Remove www-data owned file using ordinary user

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

i have a folder which contain uploaded file. for example `/var/www/app/storage/public` :

```
ls -al /var/www/app/storage/public
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 835870 Aug 22 13:42 8b4c4e2a3d64.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 835870 Aug 22 13:24 3d326ab2b3bc.pdf
```

I want to make a script to clean up that directory without using `root` user. What should i do if i want to delete those files using ordinary user like `sanders` so i can do something like:

```
sanders@localhost:~$ rm -rf /var/www/app/storage/public
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to add this user to your "www-data" group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data sanders
```

Then, make sure your folders have the correct group permissions:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/app/storage/public
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/app/storage/public
```

Comment: wow thanks.. it works... actually i have tried `sudo usermod -a -G www-data sanders` before but it didn't work.. I forgot to do `chmod -R g+w` to that directory lol.

Comment: Thanks! Adding some keywords to draw the attention of others who may have experienced similar issues: This resolves a `move`/`delete` permission for `rclone` in the case of `sftp` and `SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED`